# Forbidden: You do not have permission to access this document - When attempting to save a Template

Tags: templates, query

EE Version 2.10.1, PHP 5.3.27 Neither have been updated since installed. And as much as I would LOVE to upgrade to EE v3.x, I cannot due to some of the Add-Ons not having been upgraded.

This appears to have something to do with ExpressionEngine’s query functionality. I uninstalled the Query Module and reinstalled it, but the same issue.

Just started to receive this error about 2 hours ago. I have looked all over ExpressionEngine but cannot figure out what the issue is EXCEPT that when I use the following in PHP within the Template, it causes the above error:

$uploadTo = $this->EE->db->query( “SELECT server_path as url FROM ” . $prefix . “upload_prefs WHERE 1 = 1 and name = ‘ABC’ “);

Hmmm, it appears to be the same issue if I use the following:

{exp:query sql=”select Count(*) TheCnt from EE->db->dbprefix; ?>FrEd fred Where 1=1 and fred.ID = EE->session->userdata(‘member_id’); ?> and fred.CanDt is NULL” } {/exp:query}

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the Hosting Provider had enabled mod_security in the middle of the day (right when I had taken a slight break) without notifying me of this ahead of time.

They disabled mod_security late last night and all is working correctly now.

BTW, the error_log file on the hosting site had all sorts of errors notifying that the issue was mod_security.